# Diffusion Constant for 2D Random Walk

Tags: partial-differential-equations, random-walk

I've been investigating a 2-dimensional random walk, where the direction of a particle changes from $\theta$ to $\theta +  \Delta \theta$ every time step. The particle moves a distance $v\Delta t$ in this direction at every time step. The random variable $\Delta\theta$ I'm using is uniformly distributed along the interval $[-\eta,\eta]$ where $0<\eta\leq 2\pi$.

I'm going to use the heat equation to try and model the diffusion of such particles. To do this, I need to know how the diffusion constant $D$ depends on $\eta$. I've done some research, but everything I've found only gives a value for $D=\frac{v^2}{4}$ in the $\eta = 2\pi$ case.

I guessed that $D(\eta) = \frac{2\pi v^2}{\eta 4}$. This gives the correct expression in the $\eta = 2\pi$ case. I tried to verify this by using numerics.

I started with a large number of particles (5000) localised at $x=y=0$ I then measured how they spread through time. At each time step, I measured their full-width half-maximum, and used curve fitting to find a value for $D$. I repeated this process many times, for many different values of $\eta$.

[This is the curve I produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAAeF.png)

The black line is $D = \frac{v^2}{4}$.

My ansatz is not correct. Can anyone show me how $D$ would depend on $\eta$?

Comment: I'm confused by your results  - shouldn't choosing an angle uniformly in $[-\pi,\pi]$ give identical results to $[-2\pi, 2\pi]$? Can you also explain exactly what $D$ is? I would not expect this process to correspond to any standard diffusion operator $\partial_t - D \Delta$ unless $\eta$ is a multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: For example if $\eta$ is very small, the probability density after $N$ steps would be concentrated in an annulus near the circle of radius of $vN$. The heat equation with any $D$ would give a Gaussian.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the original post - the numbers are selected uniformly from $-\frac{\eta}{2}$ to $\frac{\eta}{2}$. $D$ corresponds to the  constant of diffusion in the heat equation i.e $\frac{\partial c}{\partial t} = D \nabla c$.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense. I'd suggest using your numerics to visualize the endpoint distribution for a few values of $D$ and check whether the distribution actually looks like a Gaussian or not - if (as I expect) it does not, then the heat equation using some fitted value of $D$ will not be an accurate model.